# Error: unexpected symbol in "f <- function(a,b){print(a) print"

Tags: r, function

Sorry that this is going to be a stupid question. I program in C++ and don't know R. Why can't I get this function to print out two parameters? The function goes like:

```
> f <- function(a,b){print(a) print(b)}
Error: unexpected symbol in "f <- function(a,b){print(a) print"
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial which just assumes this function will work while testing the errors with different parameters (like a missing parameter) but this function won't even be allowed.

Comment: Why are you programming in R without reading the tutorial?  Despite common lore, it's not possible to learn a code language by osmosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon is missing. You should have written:

```
f <- function(a,b){print(a) ; print(b)}
```

or

```
 f <- function(a,b){
     print(a)
     print(b)
 }
```